# d3 date/time plotting out by 100 years

Tags: date, d3.js, plot

Can anyone help a beginner d3'er?  I've created a scatter plot using d3 that shows Filing Date  (of a Document Family) on the x-axis, and # family Members on the y-axis.  Dots are all the same radius and are colour coded by Status.  I have 300+ data records in a csv file format and all but the first 4 of them plot perfectly.  All dates are post 1900.

Included below are the first 9 lines of the csv data set.(I've used line breaks here to make it a bit more readable).  The first 4 records are plotting out at +100 years on their actual date.  e.g. 1934 plots as 2034.... but the 3-Nov-75 and the ~300 others all plot as expected. The data came from an Excel spreadsheet, all date cells were formatted the same way, all show the correct 4-digit date year, and none behave as text strings instead of dates.  The date display format in Excel was dd-mmm-yy.

```
Num,Word,FilingDate,Status,Type,FamNum
63872,Word1,23-May-34,Removed,Word,2
69105,Word2,19-Oct-36,Registered,Word,1
175164,Word3,31-Jul-62,Registered,Word,6
207804,Word4,1-Feb-67,Registered,Word,6
291765,Word5,3-Nov-75,Registered,Word,12
381067,Word6,15-Sep-82,Removed,Word,2
381069,Word7,15-Sep-82,Removed,Word,2
402936,Word8,27-Jan-84,Removed,Word,2
410476,Word9,20-Jun-84,Removed,Word,2
```

I've included the following in the html code, which is working for all but the first 4 records.

```
// Parse the date/time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be going haywire?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to hack a little to produce the date you wish.

Instead of using

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

create a new function to parse your date:

```
var parseDate = function(d){
  var last2 = parseInt(d.slice(-2));
  var date = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse(d)
  if(last2 < 69){//if year is less than 69 then change the year
          date.setFullYear(1900 + last2);//will generate 1900 date
  }
    return date
}
```

Comment: This is correct. It would be nice to see an explanation and a reference to the culprit, though: [`d3_time_expandYear()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/locale/time-format.js#L300-L302)

Comment: What really boggles my mind is the fact, that it is 68, whereas normal JS dates use the Unix reference time stamp January 1, 1970. I am curious if someone can come with an explanation for that!

Comment: thanks for the answer and the comments. I have the graph part working nicely now.  I have another issue re tooltips that I'll post a question up about separately.